# JQuery UI Slider: change from range to single handle

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I have two sliders that each start with a single value and handle. When one slider is moved, the other slide is changed to a range slider with two handles.

```
$( ".factor-slider").slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    value: 3,
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        updateSliders(event, ui);
    }
});
function updateSliders(event, ui) {
    $("#slider-costs").slider("option", "range", true); // turn on range option
    $("#slider-costs").slider("values", 0, 2); // set min to x
    $("#slider-costs").slider("values", 1, 4); // set max to x
}
```

This is working well. My problem occurs when I try to change a range slider back to a slider with a single value and one handle. I use this code to set range to false and set a single value of 3:

```
function resetAll() {
    $(".factor-slider").slider("option", "range", false);
    $(".factor-slider").slider("value", 3);
}
```

The first handle correctly moves to 3, but the second handle never disappears. I was expecting that setting range to false would do this. I also tried adding this line to clear the second value:

```
$(".factor-slider").slider("option", "values", [3])
```

which made no difference. Do I need to do something specific to delete/remove the second handle?

Here's my attempt at a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mcpabjen/2/). Move the Mission slider to turn the Costs slider into a range slider. Click Reset to turn Costs slider back into a single handle slider, but see that the 2nd handle doesn't disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon a rearrangement that seems to work (though I'm not sure why the "values" setter needs to be there):

```
function resetAll() {
    $(".factor-slider").slider("option", "values", [3]);
    $(".factor-slider").slider("value", 3);
    $(".factor-slider").slider("option", "range", false);
}
```